# Is there a way to grab more Users with "message.guild.members"?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a discord bot, and I'm trying to grab a member list of a server, but when I use `message.guild.members` it just returns 5 random members, plus anyone on that server the bot has a DM chat with.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

#[...]

    members = message.guild.members

#[...]
```

Edit: This if for a selfbot. If I put in a normal bot token, it works fine.

Comment: Do you have [`intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=#discord.Intents.members) enabled?

Answer (score -1):

first of all: you need to have intense true (to enable it go to [Discord Developpers](https://discord.com/developers/))

secondly: do this code (you need to do a for loop to get all members:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = message.channel
    members = message.guild.members
    result = ""
    for i in members:
        result += i + "\n"
    await ctx.send(result)
```

Comment: I don't see how the code is relevant, the question just asked to put them in a list.